# A chart install (or helm_release via terraform) always results in "failed to download <chart>"

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, helm

When installing a `helm` chart directly (with helm 3), or using the `helm` provider in `terraform`, the same error is thrown which implies the download fails, something like:

```
Error: failed to download "https://agones.dev/chart/stable/agones-1.7.0.tgz" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

Running the repo update has no effect, nor does deleting the cache, trying a different release, different versions of Helm 3. However, `wget` (or similar) has no issue with fetching the chart, and the contents of the chart look correct, and even install when run as a local file rather than a remote download.

However, that cannot be used as a workaround in the case of something like the `helm` provider in terraform which expects a repository and will not accept `file://` as a protocol for that definition. How to fix this permanently, and so that it "just works" again with terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is very difficult to debug in `Terraform` but the fact that it fails with a direct install allows for more information to be obtained, by adding a `--debug` flag to the command:

```
helm --debug install agones https://agones.dev/chart/stable/agones-1.7.0.tgz -n agones-system
```

Now the error is more verbose and the cause becomes obvious:

```
Error: no cached repo found. (try 'helm repo update'): open ~/.cache/helm/repository/local-index.yaml: no such file or directory
```

The local cache as defined in `~/.config/helm/repositories.yaml` is missing. The likely reason for this is a `helm` v2 to v3 upgrade or perhaps a bug in the initial repo config, it can be fixed by creating the file as follows:

```
cp ~/.helm/repository/local/index.yaml ~/.cache/helm/repository/local-index.yaml
```

Once the file has been copied all helm operations should return to normal. If you don't have a copy of the file for whatever reason, it is very easy to create from scratch, here is what the contents of mine looked like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
entries: {}
generated: "2020-07-14T18:21:24.471657624+01:00"
```

Just create the file manually with an appropriate timestamp and your errors should disappear.

Note: this was originally answered [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/537#issuecomment-658352734) (by me also), adding to ServerFault to help discoverability